# Bootstrap button checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
$('label > input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    var selected = 0;
    $('label.active').each(function () {
        selected++;
    });
    console.log(selected);
});
```

I use this code for when one of the bootstrap checkbox buttons change, but when I log it to the console, it isn't accurate, like

change() -> 1 active button -> console shows 0

change() -> 2 active buttons -> console shows 1

change() -> 3 active buttons -> console shows 2

change() -> 4 active buttons -> console shows 3
etc

**EDIT**
My question was maybe a bit misleading, inside the `each` I have a function I want to execute on the ekements that are active

I was just counting to see if I could find all the selected elements

```
$('label.active').each(function () {
     // Active, so do a function
     myfunc();
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: As per @Ted's answer, just add `.each(function(...` instead of `.length` for the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess the active class is added to the label on change as well, meaning it can happen after your code executes.

**Edited per OP's edit**
try

```
   $('label > input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
        var selected = 0;
        $('label > input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(index, element){
             selected++; 
             //in case you need these element:
             var $cb = $(element), //the checkbox
                 $label = $cb.parent('label'); //the checkboxs label

             //your code here

        });
        console.log(selected);
    });
```

Comment: I noticed similar behavior when trying a solution out. As you say, directly selecting the checked checkboxes will likely avoid weird situations around bootstrap not applying `.active` to labels

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('label > input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    var selected = $('label.active').length;
    console.log(selected);
});
```

Just get the length of the array and make that the total number selected.